# Rails 4 - How to access to gem precompiled assets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have an application an I'm precompiling the assets to deploy to Heroku. I'm using a [gem](https://github.com/bmc/jquery-raty-rails) which uses some internal images. I run.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And the images are compiled, in fact i can see them in the `public/assets/jquery.raty/` directory (where they should be). E.g.

```
myapp/public/assets/jquery.raty/star-on-4db6f75f3608bbd77fa4bc3959097c33.png
```

The problem is the gem's javascript cannot find the images because it's referencing to them internally (). So, I've changed the configuration to add the images using <%= asset_path "filename" %> (I changed the file to `.js.erb`). Locally works ok (because I'm not precompiling in development), but after deploying to heroku, the images are referenced like

```
/assets/jquery.raty/star-on.png
```

Without the md5 fingerprint.

Somebody knows what am I doing wrong? Or there's something I'm missing when precompilng gem assets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that `asset_path` doesn't use the fingerprints for the images. I had to use `image_path` and tweak a little bit to make it work with the library.

Comment: i am facing the same problem. Can you please elaborate on your answer. It would be really helpful.

Comment: Basically you should use `image_path` instead of `asset_path`. Then just check with your browser developer tools for the path generated and tweak accordingly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

For info, I had to do the following to get it to work properly for me:

```
$('#star').raty({
  starOn: '<%= image_path('star-on.png') %>',
  starOff: '<%= image_path('star-off.png') %>',
  path: '',
  scoreName: 'star',
  space: true 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this way worked for me

```
  $(this).raty({
    scoreName: "seller_rating",
    starOn: '<%= asset_url 'star-repassa-on.png' %>',
    starOff: '<%= asset_path 'star-repassa-off.png' %>',
    path: '',
    readOnly: true,
    score: function () {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  })
```